# Sandbox electron app using electron-builder

Tags: sandbox, electron, electron-builder

Is there any option to provide entitlements file while using electron-builder? I want to sandbox my app; but do not see any option in the wiki or docs for electron-builder.

Also, electron-builder uses electron-packager underneath and electron-packager does allow that option.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify any electron-packager option in the [build](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#build) field.

Comment: couldn't find it in the docs. is this still possible? could provide the config for the build field?